# Why Checkbox [checked] is firing multiple times for all options

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am creating a form which have a field with checkbox (multiple options).
I will use such kind of field in many places in my application and that's why I decided to use an directive for this functionality.

What I noticed is that Angular2 is not supporting checkbox (multiple options) in a nice way.
Because of that I am using `[checked]` options for a checkbox to verify if the checkbox is checked or not and `(change)` to update my model.

During development I noticed that on clicking on the checkbox - `[checked]` is firing multiple times and also is checking all options not only this in which I clicked.

I created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHuHXsTKaE7y0hybuZiv?p=preview) to show you what I`m talking about.

I am wondering why `[checked]` is firing multiple times (in this plunkr twice) and it`s checking all options not only the clicked one?

Comment: If you run `enableProdMode()` it will be once. The click is firing `ApplicationRef.tick` and then all functions is 
executed in your view by `detectChangesInternal`

Answer (score 2):

`[checked]` is called by Angular2s change detection every time change detection runs (for every event or `setTimeout` or similar async calls) for every option to figure out if the `checked` property of the items needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my opinion this is a strange functionality and maybe this is making Angular slower. What  do you think?

Comment: I don't think it's strange. Thus is how Angular2 and change detection works. Binding to methods is discouraged anyway. Instead assign the value to a property and bind to that property. If the method doesn't do expensive work it might still be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's how Angular works. You change some part of your application's model an Angular is checking the "zone" where the model is (it's more complicated, you should search for Zones in Angular).

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html

Answer (score 0):

i have create Multicheckbox component in angular2. please check Plunker Url: [Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K01n9vmSZyMi0VF5Nf1x?p=preview)

Please import this component in your application and use it all places multiple time.

**1) multicheckbox.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

declare var $:any;
//var chkSelectedArr=[];

/**
 * Define input data interface
 */
export interface chkArrayInterface {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

/**
 * checked checkbox to array
 */
@Pipe({ name: 'chkChecked', pure: false })
export class ChkChecked implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args): any {
        if(args !== undefined && args.length !== 0){
            if(args.includes(value)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * filter checkbox list
 */
@Pipe({ name: 'filter', pure: true })
export class FilterPipe{
  transform(items: any[], args: any): any {
    let filter = args.toString();
    if(filter !== undefined && filter.length !== null){
        if(filter.length === 0 || items.length ===0){
            return items;
        }else{
            return filter ? items.filter(item=> item.title.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : items;
        }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Multi select checkbox component
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'multi-checkbox',
    pipes: [FilterPipe, ChkChecked],
    //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template : `
    <div class="custom-multicheck-box">
        <div class="input-group custom-search-box" *ngIf="isFilter">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  (keyup)="changeFilter()" (input)="txtSearch = $event.target.value" [value]="txtSearch" [placeholder]="filterTitle" />
            <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="resetSearch()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-list-box" [style.height]="height">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelectAll" (change)="selectAll($event)" />
        <span class="select-all">Select All</span>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let chk of chkArray | filter:txtSearch">
                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk.id | chkChecked: chkSelected " (change)="selectChk($event,chk.id)" />
                <span>{{chk?.title}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,

    styles: [`
        .custom-multicheck-box { 
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
            border-radius: .25rem;
            padding: 5px 0;
            left: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: reletive
        }

        .custom-list-box {
            margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
            color: #0082c6;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .custom-search-box {
            margin: 7px;
        }

        li {
            padding-top: 3px;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: .8125rem;
        }

        li > span {
            margin-left:10px;
        }

        span.select-all {
            margin-left:10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: .8125rem;
        }

        .input-group-addon .glyphicon-remove-sign {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    `]
})

export class MultiCheckboxComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  { 
    @Input() chkArray: chkArrayInterface[]=[];
    @Input() chkSelected: Array<any>=[];
    @Input() filterTitle: string="Filter";
    @Input() isFilter: boolean=true;
    @Input() height: string="100px";
    @Output() chkResult: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private txtSearch:string="";
    private chkSelectedArr:any[]=[];
    private isSelectAll:boolean;
    private fiteredArr:any;
    private filterPipe:any;
    constructor() {
        this.isSelectAllCheckbox();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        this.isSelectAllCheckbox();
    }

    /**
     * Checked is selectAll or not
     */
    isSelectAllCheckbox(){
        if(this.chkArray !== undefined && this.chkArray !== null 
           && this.chkSelected !== undefined && this.chkSelected!==null){

            if(this.chkArray.length === this.chkSelected.length && this.chkArray.length !==0){
                this.isSelectAll = true;
            }else{
                this.isSelectAll = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Select all then all checkbox selected
     */
    selectAll(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.filterPipe = new FilterPipe();
        this.fiteredArr = this.filterPipe.transform(this.chkArray,this.txtSearch);

        this.chkSelected = [];
        this.isSelectAll = event.target.checked;
        if(this.fiteredArr !== undefined && event.target.checked === true && this.fiteredArr.length !==0){
            this.fiteredArr.forEach(chk => {
                this.chkSelected.push(chk.id);
            });
        }

        this.chkResult.emit({
          value: this.chkSelected
        })
    }

    /**
     * Select perticular checkbox
     */
    selectChk(event, val){
        if(event.target.checked === true){
            this.chkSelected.push(val);
        }else{
            var index = this.chkSelected.indexOf(val);
            this.chkSelected.splice(index, 1);
        }

        this.isSelectAllCheckbox();

        this.chkResult.emit({
          value: this.chkSelected
        })
    }

    /**
     * Reset filter checkbox
     */
    resetSearch(){
        this.txtSearch="";
        this.changeFilter();
    }

    /**
     * Check on filter selected all or not
     */
    changeFilter(){
         this.filterPipe = new FilterPipe();
        this.fiteredArr = this.filterPipe.transform(this.chkArray,this.txtSearch);
        if(this.fiteredArr !== undefined && this.chkSelected !== undefined){
            if(this.fiteredArr.length === this.chkSelected.length && this.fiteredArr.length !== 0){
                this.isSelectAll = true;
            }else{
                this.isSelectAll = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for tour answer. The Plunker is not working. I made my own directive but I had problem with validation if some of the checkboxes is checked

Comment: Yes now is working. Before there was some issue. BTW. Definitely is helpful but is not the answer which I was looking for. Also in my case the checkboxes are in Form (FormGroup).

Comment: This example is not your answer. But, try to helpful some point of view.